# route not working in angularjs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, routes

I am using angular along with node.
I am using routes to redirect page.

Onto my html page i have defined 2 links as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  >
<head>
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/javascript/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="/webstorm1/app.js"></script>
    <script src="../controllers/registration.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="test">
    <a ng-href="#/login">Login</a>
    <a ng-href="#/register">Register</a>
</div>
<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and onto the app.js file i have defined the route as:

```
var test =  angular.module('test', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
console.log('test');
        $routeProvider.when('/register',
            {
                templateUrl: '/webstorm1/partials/register.html',
                controller: 'registration'

            });
        $routeProvider.when('/login',
            {
                templateUrl: '../partials/login.html',
                controller: 'login'
            });


    });
```

when i run the html file and click on register link, it prints the 'test', but doesnot show the page on browser.

Comment: Please see network log for 404 errors for views referenced. Also look console for errors.

Comment: @Chandermani : there is no logs on console.

Comment: Try moving your `ng-app="test"` to the `html` or `body` tag.

Comment: perfect..thanks working now....

Comment: @Vucko, You should post your comment as the answer so the OP can use it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck your right - I've added an answer

Comment: Thanks you Vucko, @Kawade, please accept Vucko's answer if this resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<div ng-view></div>` is outside of `<div ng-app="test">` scope.

```
<div ng-app="test">                         <!-- ng-app starts -->
    <a ng-href="#/login">Login</a>
    <a ng-href="#/register">Register</a>
</div>                                      <!-- ng-app ends  -->
<div ng-view></div>                         <!-- outside from ng-app  -->
```

Simply put that `ng-app="test"` to some parent element like `body` or `html` to make all elements inside their scope.